Как сделать, чтобы счетчик срабатывал только один раз при достижении блока?
Как сделать, чтобы счетчик срабатывал только один раз при достижении блока , сейчас код срабатывает каждый раз, когда я возвращаюсь к блоку


  class countUp {
    constructor(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.setVars();
      this.init();
    }
  
    setVars() {
      this.number = this.el.querySelectorAll("[data-countup-number]");
      this.observerOptions = { root: null, rootMargin: "0px 0px", threshold: 0 };
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          const end = parseFloat(
            entry.target.dataset.countupNumber.replace(/,/g, "")
          );
          const decimals = this.countDecimals(end);
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            this.iterateValue(entry.target, end, decimals);
          }
        });
      }, this.observerOptions);
    }
  
    init() {
      if (this.number.length > 0) {
        this.number.forEach((el) => {
          this.observer.observe(el);
        });
      }
    }
  
    iterateValue(el, end, decimals) {
      const start = 0;
      const duration = 2500;
      let startTimestamp = null;
  
      const step = (timestamp) => {
        if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
        const elapsedPercent = (timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration;
        const easedProgress = Math.min(this.easeOutQuint(elapsedPercent), 1);
        let interimNumber = Math.abs(easedProgress * (end - start) + start);
        el.innerHTML = this.formatNumber(interimNumber, decimals);
        if (easedProgress < 1) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
      };

      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  
    easeOutQuad(x) {
      return 1 - Math.pow(1 - x, 3);
    }
  
    easeOutQuint(x) {
      return 1 - Math.pow(1 - x, 5);
    }
  
    countDecimals(val) {
      if (Math.floor(val) === val) return 0;
      return val.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
    }
  
    formatNumber(val, decimals) {
      return val.toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
        minimumFractionDigits: decimals,
        maximumFractionDigits: decimals
      });
    }
  }
  const dataModules = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-module="countup"]')];
  
  dataModules.forEach((element) => {
    element.dataset.module.split(" ").forEach(function () {
      new countUp(element);
    });
  });




Тут есть ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684503/intersection-observer-call-a-function-only-once-per-element
